# How does Hadoop MapReduce WordCount take input as <key, value> pairs?

Tags: hadoop, dictionary, mapreduce

How does the `WordCount` MapReduce application take input as a set of <key, value> pairs? It seems like it instead takes an input set of words.

From [the Apache Hadoop MapReduce Tutorial](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/stable/hadoop-mapreduce-client/hadoop-mapreduce-client-core/MapReduceTutorial.html):

1. "The MapReduce framework operates exclusively on <key, value> pairs, that is, the framework views the **input** to the job **as a set of <key, value> pairs**..."
2. "(input) <k1, v1> -> map"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This tutorial hasn't gone into the details yet. There is an `InputFormat` and an `OutputFormat` that is defined for every MapReduce program.

An `InputFormat` defines what the key and a value is for a given record.

A `RecordReader` defines what a record is from a given input file.(there is a little more to this)

In the `WordCount` program, the default `InputFormat` is [TextInputFormat](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapred/TextInputFormat.html), which takes in `LongWritable` as the key and `Text` as the value for every record; And every record in this program is a line(by default). The key here is the byte offset of the line and the value is the line of text. I think you have missed [**this**](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/stable/hadoop-mapreduce-client/hadoop-mapreduce-client-core/MapReduceTutorial.html#Job_Input) part from the tutorial.

Comment: When you say there is a little more to `RecordReader`, can you elaborate on that?

Comment: i'm sure that I can't explain better than the official tutorial you are learning from. Go through the complete document, everything you want to know is in reasonable detail in the tutorial.